# Is there a way to force HTTP?

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have a client with a bunch of one-page websites that is hosting with Godaddy. Of course they don't offer Let's Encrypt SSLs and we don't want to have to renew SSL certificates every 3 months. They noticed that if they go to the HTTPS version of the site it says it is insecure (since it doesn't have an SSL certificate). They have asked me if I can force these to redirect to HTTP. I have found `.htaccess` rules but they don't work because modern browsers check for certs before hitting `.htaccess`.

Is there a way to make them redirect? We are using Wordpress for all of them.

Comment: You can't redirect HTTPS to HTTP in a way that doesn't say that the site is insecure.  It is not allowed / supported because doing that is insecure.  (Basically you are trying to get the user's browser to lie to the user about the security of their session.)

Comment: There is no 'HTTPS version of the site' unless there is an SSL certificate, so there must be one, albeit self-signed or expired. Please don't copy GoDaddy's technical illiteracy by talking about 'an SSL'. You mean SSL *certificate*. SSL is a network protocol.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I didn't think it was possible but they don't want to pay Godaddy for a new SSL cert  for each website and since they aren't using subdomains they would have to buy 12 or 13 certs. I will suggest they move to another host with Let's Encrypt or that they switch to subdomains if they want to not have this issue.